# Pl/Sql using instr to find exact match

Tags: string, oracle, plsql, extract, substr

I am trying to find if a string exist in a word and extract it. I have uses the `instr()` function but this works as the LIKE function: if part or the whole word exists it returns it.

Here I want to get the string 'Services' out, it works but if I change 'Services' to 'Service' it still works. I don't want that. If 'Service' is entered it should return null and not 'Services'

Modified:

What I am trying to do here is abbreviate certain parts of the company name.

This is what my database table looks like :

```
Word     | Abb
---------+-----  
Company  | com
Limited  | ltd
Service  | serv
Services | servs
```

Here is the code:

```
Declare 

    Cursor Words Is

    SELECT word,abb
    FROM abbWords


    processingWord VARCHAR2(50);
    abbreviatedName VARCHAR(120);
    fullName = 'A.D Company Services Limited';

BEGIN

    FOR eachWord IN Words LOOP


      --find the position of the word in name
       wordPosition := INSTR(fullName, eachWord.word);

       --extracts the word form the full name that matches the database
       processingWord := Substr(fullName,instr(fullName,eachWord.word), length(eachWord.word));

      --only process words that exist in name
      if wordPosition > 0 then
           abbreviatedName = replace(fullName, eachWord.word,eachWord.abb);
       end if;

    END lOOP;

END;
```

So if the user enters 'Service' I don't want 'Services' to be returned.  By this I mean word position should be 0 if the word 'Service' in not found instead of returning the position for the word 'Services'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative is to use something like:

```
select replace(name,' serv ', ' Services ')
from names;
```

This will replace only the word 'Serv' situated between 2 spaces.

Thank you,
Alex.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing it:

```
DECODE(INSTR('A.D Company Seervices Limited','Services'),
              0,
              NULL,
              SUBSTR('A.D Company Services Limited',
                  INSTR('A.D Company Services Limited','Services'),
                  length('Services')))
```

[`INSTR()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) will return 0 if text is not found. [`DECODE()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) will evaluate the first argument, compare to the second, if match, return third argument, if not, return fourth argument. ([sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/afbc3/9/0))

Arguably not the most elegant way, but matches your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're over-complicating this. You can do everything with [regular expressions](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html). For instance; given the following table:

```
create table names ( name varchar2(100));
insert into names values ('A.D Company Services Limited');
insert into names values ('A.D Company Service Limited');
```

This query will only return the name `'A.D Company Services Limited'`.

```
select *
  from names
 where regexp_like( name
                  , '(^|[[:space:]])services($|[[:space:]])'
                  , 'i' )
```

This means match the beginning of the string, `^`, or a space followed by services followed the end of the string, `$`, or a space. This is what differentiates regular expressions from using `instr` etc. You can make your matches easily conditional on other factors.

However, though this seems to be your question I don't think this is what you're trying to do. You're trying to replace the string `'serv'` in your wider string without replacing `'services'` or `'service'`. For this you need to use [`regexp_replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions149.htm#SQLRF06302).

If I add the following row to the table:

```
insert into names values ('A.D Company Serv Limited');
```

and run this query:

```
select regexp_replace( name
                     , '(^|[[:space:]])serv($|[[:space:]])'
                     , ' Services '
                     , 1, 0, 'i' )
  from names
```

The *only* thing that will change is `' Serv '`, which in this newest line, will be replaced with `' Services '`. Note the spaces; as you don't want to replace `'Services'` with `'ServServices'` these are very important.

#### Here's a [little SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90466/9) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

[`INSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions080.htm#i77598) returns a number: the index of the first occurrence of the matching string. You should use [`regexp_substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#i1239858) instead (10g+):

```
SQL> select regexp_substr('A.D Company Services Limited', 'Services') match,
  2         regexp_substr('A.D Company Service Limited', 'Services') unmatch
  3  from dual;

MATCH    UNMATCH
-------- -------
Services
```

Comment: This will not work for me what i am doing is selecting all the words form my word table into a cursor and then i am looping thru the records in the cursor looking for words in the 'A.D Company Services Limited' that exist in the table. So i am using the instr function to look for the word Service and Services both which exist in my cursor in the Company Name it processes both Services and Service.

Comment: @dev_darin: Sorry I don't understand your requirement. Maybe you should rewrite your question with the expected result for each case.